# Node.js data encrypted with AES-256-GCM cannot be decrypted with Java

Tags: javascript, java, aes, aes-gcm

### Node.js Encryption Algorithm

```
import crypto from "crypto"
function(data, key) {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12)
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv)
    let enc = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64')
    enc += cipher.final('base64')
    return [enc, cipher.getAuthTag().toString('base64'), iv.toString("base64")].join('.')
}
```

### Java Decrypt  Algorithm

```
public static String decrypt(String encryData) throws Exception {
        String[] parts = encryData.split("\\.");
        byte[] encrypted = parts[0].getBytes();
        byte[] tag = parts[1].getBytes();
        byte[] iv = parts[2].getBytes();

        GCMParameterSpec ivSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), "AES"), ivSpec);
        cipher.update(tag);
        byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return new String(bytes);
    }
```

### Java throws the following exception

Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!

Comment: Just a quick shot - I'm missing the Base64-decoding in your Java code for ciphertext, IV and gcm-tag. Second (I'm not sure): concatenate ciphertext | gcm-tag before sending to the cipher.final method.

Comment: The order of concatenation is wrong. Currently you concatenate tag|ciphertext. You need ciphertext|tag, i.e. swap `encrypted` and `tag` in the update/doFinal lines: `cipher.update(encrypted); byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(tag);`. Don't forget to specify the encoding in `new String()`.

Comment: Were you able to work this out? base64 Encoding the iv and tag was giving me size of 16 and 24 bytes respectively so in backend, I used Base64.getDecoder().decode() to decode the iv and tag and got 12 and 16 bytes in iv and tag. Yet I still get "Tag mismatch!" error on cipher.doFinal(encrypted) line.